# ASP.NET Core How to dynamically remove list element?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want a user to be able to edit the order and delete some items. To do this, for each item I added a delete button (you can see it in the code below).

Partial view Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Item.cshtml (Attribute data-id is hardcoded, because I have no idea how to pass the current OrderItem Id):

```
@model TimeTracker.Models.OrderItem
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Product" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Product" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Product" class="text-danger"></span>
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="btnDel" data-id="1" value="Remove" />
</div>
```

In ajax call comes the error in the console, which refers to the controller method. Here I am assuming I filled in the parameter `data` in ajax call incorrectly. I really don't know how to fill it in correctly in my case.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()
> :5001/Orders/RemoveItem:1

Ajax call:

```
$("#btnDel").on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        data: { order: $('#form').serialize(), orderItemId: $('#btnDel').data('id') },
        type: "DELETE",
        url: '/TaskTypes/RemoveItem',
        success: function (partialView) {
            console.log("partialView: " + partialView);
            $('#itemsContainer').html(partialView);
        }
    });
});
```

Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> RemoveItem([Bind("OrderItems")] Order order, int orderItemId)
{
    order.OrderItems.RemoveAll(c => c.Id == orderItemId);
    return PartialView("Items", order);
}
```

Comment: 405 means *Method Not Allowed*. Now, your ajax call has a type `DELETE` while your endpoint is attributed with `[HttpPost]`. You should be revisiting that and make a correction there.

Comment: @SaiGummaluri When I tried `type: "POST"`, i got 400 error.

Comment: 400 mean *Bad Request*. Do you see any errors on the console of your browser?

Answer (score 1):

When you use **ValidateAntiForgeryToken** You have to pass RequestVerificationToken in your ajax header to validate your request.

Please visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1 for more details about prevent cross site request.